# Do I need an XML parser to read and write and xml file in lua or can I use io,open?

Tags: xml, lua

Well I need to read an xml file, and then change the values of one of the variables in an xml file through lua, I am having trouble installing a parser for windows and was wondering if the io.open function would work as it is just one xml file and I am only changing 2 numbers, could you post some examples if there is a way! thank you in advance!

Comment: If you could post some example input and expected output, it'll help us answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the XML yourself, or use a library.

[Here are some libraries and examples.](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaXml)